# .htaccess redirection domain/folder/name to domain/folder/name.php

Tags: .htaccess

My domain will be example.com
within I have a folder named staff
within I have a file names my_boss.php

I am trying to write an htaccess rule when someone writes:
example.com/staff/my_boss
they will be redirected to example.com/staff/my_boss.php

tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite URL to staff folder
RewriteRule ^staff/([^/]+)$ /staff/$1.php [L]
```

no success. I get a 404 error

.htaccess file is working and rewrite mod is active.

Any help rendered is greatly appreciated

Comment: The rule should work, though certainly some details could be discussed. You _claim_ that your configuration file gets interpreted (how did you make sure?). So there is little we can help here. The usual hints: does your http server's error log file contain anything of value for your test requests? And how did you make sure that you are not looking at client side cached results of prior attempts?

Comment: ty arkascha. I found out what the problem was. will add it as answer for others

Answer (score 0):

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
The problem was that the /etc/mime.types file ,the PHP part was commented out.
After uncommenting and restarting apache the htaccess worked.

```
#application/x-httpd-php                        phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

Comment: That does not explain the http status 404 you got back. This would only heave let to you receiving the actual php code being delivered to the requesting client.

Comment: Also I wonder why you apparently try to configure this in a purely manual manner. All of the Linux distributions typically used these days offer a modular setup that takes care of such details on an installation package based level.

Comment: Clean minimal install of Ubuntu 22.04 and manual installation of lamp, then php mods for sqlsrv for interacting with MSSQL on a windows server machine. My cloud provider only had predefined Lamp for Ubuntu 20.4 and pear refused to work on their installation. Figured it was easier to just install it manually

Comment: What do you actually mean by "manual installation of lamp"? Obviously Ubuntu comes with perfectly usable preconfigured packages for all LAMP components. That is what I referred to. If you used those then php would habe gotten configured correctly. I understand that you manually downloaded some package from somewhere to install them (maybe even build them), but _why_ ?

Comment: like this: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/lamp-applications
?????
I was not aware of them
and I did not just download some package. I followed this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: That is not a manual install, but a perfectly normal package based setup. As it should be. And there are some additional points covered in those tutorials. If you followed those steps then installing the php packages should have taken care of registering the mime types. If not then you either wrote over them afterwards by copying some other configuration or you received an error during installation which you ignored. But above modification definitely should be nothing you have to manually adjust. Anyway, great that you found your solution. Have fun!